# Trying to add a column to a data file

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have a data file with 2 columns, x ranging from -5 to 4 and f(x). I need to add a third column with |f(x)| the absolute value of f(x). Then I need to export the 3 columns as a new data file.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
from numpy import *
data = genfromtxt("task1.dat")
c = []
ab = abs(data[:,1])
ablist = ab.tolist()
datalist = data.tolist()
c.append(ablist)
c.append (datalist)
A = asarray (c)
savetxt("task1b.dat", A)
```

It gives me the following error message for line "`A = asarray(c)`":

```
ValueError : setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Does someone know a quick and efficient way to add this column and export the data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a list within a list in `c`.

Anyway, I think this is much clearer:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("task1.dat")
data_new = np.hstack((data, np.abs(data[:,-1]).reshape((-1,1))))
np.savetxt("task_out.dat", data_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a list and when you execute

```
c.append(ablist)
c.append (datalist)
```

it appends 2 lists of different shapes to the list `c`. It will probably end up looking like this

```
c == [ [ [....],[....]], [....]]
```

which is not possible to be parsed by numpy.asarray due to that shape difference
(I am saying probably because I am assuming there is a 2d matrix in `genfromtxt("task1.dat")`)

what you can do to concatenate the columns is

```
from numpy import *
data = genfromtxt("task1.dat")
ab = abs(data[:,1])
c = concatenate((data,ab.reshape(-1,1),axis=1)
savetxt("task1b.dat", c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a 2d array like:

```
In [54]: data=np.arange(-5,5).reshape(5,2)

In [55]: data
Out[55]: 
array([[-5, -4],
       [-3, -2],
       [-1,  0],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4]])

In [56]: ab=abs(data[:,1])
```

There are various ways to `concatenate` 2 arrays.  In this case, `data` is 2d, and `ab` is 1d, so you have to take some steps to ensure they are both 2d.  `np.column_stack` does that for us.

```
In [58]: np.column_stack((data,ab))
Out[58]: 
array([[-5, -4,  4],
       [-3, -2,  2],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  4]])
```

With a little change in indexing we could make `ab` a column array from that start, and simply `concatenate` on the 2nd axis:

```
ab=abs(data[:,[1]])   
np.concatenate((data,ab),axis=1)
```

==================

The same numbers with your `tolist` produce a `c` like

```
In [72]: [ab.tolist()]+[data.tolist()]
Out[72]: [[4, 2, 0, 2, 4], [[-5, -4], [-3, -2], [-1, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

That is not good input for `array`.

To go the list route you need to do an iteration over a zip:

```
In [86]: list(zip(data,ab))
Out[86]: 
[(array([-5, -4]), 4),
 (array([-3, -2]), 2),
 (array([-1,  0]), 0),
 (array([1, 2]), 2),
 (array([3, 4]), 4)]

In [87]: c=[]

In [88]: for i,j in zip(data,ab):
    c.append(i.tolist()+[j])
   ....:     

In [89]: c
Out[89]: [[-5, -4, 4], [-3, -2, 2], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 4]]

In [90]: np.array(c)
Out[90]: 
array([[-5, -4,  4],
       [-3, -2,  2],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  4]])
```

Obviously this will be slower than the array concatenate, but studying this might help you understand both arrays and lists.